# Comparing items within a list with each other

Tags: python, list, comparison

If I have a list

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and I want to show that two items exist one of which is larger than the other by 1, can I do this **without** specifying which items in the list?

ie. without having to do something like:

```
lst[1] - lst[0] == 1
```

a general code that works for any int items in the `lst`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pair the numbers if the one less than the number is in the list:

```
new = [(i, i - 1) for i in lst if i - 1 in lst]
```

Comment: i didn't copy the exact thing, but it's what gave me the idea for:

Answer (score 1):

This one: makes set of the list for faster member checks; then short circuiting checks if `i + 1` exists in that set for each `i` in the list (I iterate over list instead of the newly created set because it should be slightly faster). As soon as it is proven that any `i + 1` also is in the list, the function exits with `True` return value, `False` otherwise.

```
def has_n_and_n_plus_1(lst):
    lset = set(lst)
    return any(i + 1 in lset for i in lst)
```

Testing:

```
>>> has_n_and_n_plus_1([6,2,7,11,42])
True
>>> has_n_and_n_plus_1([6,2,9,11,42])
False
```

---

The all tricks in 1 basket brain-teaser one:

```
from operator import sub
from itertools import starmap, tee

a, b = tee(sorted(lst))
next(b, None)
exists = 1 in starmap(sub, zip(b, a))
```

What this code does is: sort the list in increasing order; then do the pairwise iteration of `a, b = lst[i], lst[i + 1]`, then starmaps each `b, a` into the `sub` operator resulting in `b - a`; and then checks with `in` operator if that resulting iterator contains any `1`.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the list with itself shifted by one.

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> zip(lst, lst[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

This assumes that the list is ordered. If it is not, then you could sort it first and then filter it to exclude non matches (perhaps including the indexes in the original list if that is important). So if it's a more complex list of integers this should work:

```
>>> lst = [99,12,13,44,15,16,45,200]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> [(x,y) for (x,y) in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if x + 1 == y]
[(12, 13), (15, 16), (44, 45)]
```

The following is the equivalent using functions. The use of `izip` from `itertools` ensure the list is only iterated over once when we are looking for matches with the filter function:

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> lst = [99,12,13,44,15,16,45,200]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> filter(lambda (x,y): x+1==y, izip(lst, lst[1:]))
[(12, 13), (15, 16), (44, 45)]
```

The same could be written using for comprehensions, but personally I prefer using functions.

Comment: Emil, I don't appreciate people that downvote without explanation, which is why I'll justify my downvote. We are looking for numbers exactly one less, we are not zipping the list from index one. This is a simple list he gave us, but he is surely going to use a more complex list. Fix your answer, and I'll be sure to revoke it.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi I appreciate your explanation of why the downvote! I've expanded a bit on the explanation. Do you think it needs more work?

Comment: @Elizion what do you mean?

Comment: He means that this only works for lists in which subsequent terms differ by one. Try 3, 2, 5, 1, 4.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi That's why I added the sort in the expanded explanation... It also has the benefit of not having to iterate over the list more than necessary (searching for matches).

Comment: Sorry Emil, I still don't buy it. Do 13 and 15 differ by one? What about 16 and 44? See my answer above for a valid solution.

Comment: You're right, @MalikBrahimi. I didn't include the filtering part. Have updated the answer with it now.

Comment: There's still something unsettling about this code, but I'll revoke my downvote for the time being as it seems to be working.